# Save file on remote client

Tags: asp.net

On the IIS we have a batchjob that will be producing some pdf-files. These files shall be save/stored on anorher client. This client is not on the same network as the IIS.

If we know the clients external ip-address and the firewall etc is open for communication. Is it possible to save a file like this? Is it possible to do this kind of operation?

If so, is there anything special to take in consideration?

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

One thing I want to know is, you want to save this file on client machine by application or by any configuration on IIS. If I assume you want to save the file by application, then there is a problem if you want to save file directly on client machine. Instead of that you can give a option to download the file.

Or if you need your demand badly then you can follow some example listed here :
http://p2p.wrox.com/asp-net-1-0-1-1-basics/27181-save-file-client-machine.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13055/Save-file-on-client-computer

Comment: On the IIS we are planing to have a batchjob that will run on a schedual and produce these files. Instead of storing them on the webserver we want to store them on another machine that is not on the same network.

Comment: Have to go through the links provided above. Is that links are giving any information about your question? Please let me know your opinion

Comment: No, those links aren't of any use. We're looking for a solution for the application to save the files on the remote client. Not triggerd by the current user.